# Php replace characters matching the regular expression

Tags: php, regex-negation

I tried using preg_replace method to replace matching regular expression but i am getting the error message

> "Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '_' found"

```
$oldString = "";
$newString = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]/ig", "", $oldString);
```

Here i am trying to remove all the characters other than alphabets,numbers and underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` is not supported in PHP, remove the `g` modifier (global) will do.
Here is the [list of supported modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think php doesn't like the control g char after your trailing /.  I've been having trouble with this as well and removing the g seems to help. preg_replace has optional params it takes after the string you wish to augment where you control the number of times you wish to limit the search to, it's global by default.

[The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) says that you will set the limit with the 4th param (limit) and if you want you can pass in a count param 5th which will will give you the number of times it found the match.

For my money this is just another thing that PHP does 1/2 right, which all adds up to it being just about a perfectly 1/2 assed language.  But that's neither here nor there :)

Oh, and welcome to Stack! :)

Comment: I think the problem is the ```g```.  Either way, ```[^a-z0-9_]``` with the insensitive flag is the same as ```[^A-Za-z0-9_]``` without.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no modifier `g` for `preg_replace`.

```
$oldString = "";
$newString = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]*/i", "", $oldString);
```

Second, try to put a multiplier after your character class in order to replace more than 1 char.

Answer (score 0):

In RegEx `\W` means any non-alpha-numeric-underscore characters.  Keep in mind this will also replace spaces.

```
$oldString = "This, is not _all_ alpha-numeric";
$newString = preg_replace("/\W+/", "", $oldString);
# Gives "Thisisnot_all_alphanumeric"

$newString = preg_replace("/[^\w ]+/", "", $oldString);
# Gives "This is not _all_ alphanumeric"
```